# Bulk Update with SQL Server based on a list of primary keys

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am processing data from a database with millions of rows. I am pulling a batch of 1000 items from the database and processing them without a problem. I am not loading the whole entity and I am just pulling down a few columns of data for the batch.

What I want to do is mark the 1000 rows as processed with a single SQL command.

Something like:

```
UPDATE dbo.Clients 
SET HasProcessed = 1 
WHERE ClientID IN (...)
```

The ... is just a list of integers.

**Context**:

- Azure SQL Server 2012
- Entity Framework

  - `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

**Ideas**:

I know I could build the command as a pure string, but this would mean not using any `SqlParameter`s and not benefiting from the query plan optimization.

Also, I found some information about table-valued parameters, but this requires creating a table type and some overhead which I would like to avoid. This is just a list of integers after all.

**Question**:

Is there an easy (performant) way to do this that I am overlooking either with Entity Framework or `ExecuteSqlCommand`?

If not and using table-valued parameters is the best way, could you provide a complete example of how to convert an integer list into the simplest type and running that with the above query?

Comment: So something like this? 

`dataSource.UpdateByKey("dbo.Clients", "HasProcessed = 1", list).Exec();`

Comment: What's the trouble with the table type?? Table-valued parameters is ***the*** most appropriate way of doing this - even for "just" a list of integers! Anything else (comma-separated list, XML, whatever whacky ideas might be out there) are all terrible hacks and not nearly as clean and streamlined...

Comment: To be fair, a table valued parameter is just going to emit SQL containing a comma-separated list that populates a temp table. So unless you are using it with a stored procedure, it is just as hackish.

Comment: @Jonathan I'll look into that. Does that create a single parameterized query?

Comment: @marc Could you show me a simple example? From my understanding I would have to create the table type and I also didn't see a simple code example to convert a list to the appropriate structured sql parameter.

Comment: @RickLove It doesn't actually exist yet, I'm looking for ideas for a new mini-ORM we're building. (Think somewhere between Dapper and EF on the power/speed scale.) It would emit a single query, but it wouldn't be parameterized. https://github.com/docevaad/Chain/issues/33

Comment: Also, I don't think you'd gain much from paramterizing this query. The problem is that you would have to emit exactly the same SQL every time or it will generate a new execution plan. Which means you'd have to have exactly the same number of IDs every time, which isn't going to happen.